# Open multiple tabs and split window based on files in Vim

Tags: vim, c

I'm wondering, is there a way to open all my `*.[c]` files on different tabs, but split the window with the corresponding `*.[h]` file from the command line?

I can split one file as: `vim -O file1.c file1.h`

or in multiple tabs as: `vim -p *.[ch]` but I can't split them accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
vim -p *.c -c "tabdo split %:r.h"
```

See:

```
:help :tabdo
:help filename-modifiers
```